# elegant way to downgrade all angular components for angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular

My app is supposed to migrate from angularjs to angular.

I'm creating new angular components. Is there an elegant way to automatically  import and downgrade component?

Current code:

```
import { ColorPickerComponent } from './angular-comp/color-picker/color-picker.component';
import {FileSelectComponent } from './angular-comp/file-select/file-select.component';


export default angular
    .module('kn-components', myModuleNames)
    .directive('colorPicker', downgradeComponent({component: ColorPickerComponent}))
    .directive('fileSelect', downgradeComponent({component: FileSelectComponent}))
    .name;
```

Each time I create a component I need to do it, it's quite verbose....

For my angularjs component, for example, I did the following:

```
const myModuleNames = [];
const loadModules = require.context(".", true, /\.module.js$/);
loadModules.keys().forEach(function (key) {
    if(loadModules(key).default)
        myModuleNames.push(loadModules(key).default);
});
```

then:

```
export default angular
    .module('kn-components', myModuleNames)
```

and all my modules/components are imported

Comment: Do you really mean 'downgrade' or you mean 'upgrade'? Most people would agree that going from AngularJS to Angular is an 'upgrade'. I'm confused as to which direction your going.

Comment: I really mean downgrade

Comment: My app is supposed to migrate from angularjs to angular. => what this means? downgrade? Nope.

Comment: Please refer to this: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#upgrading-with-ngupgrade.
If you have an answer to my question, you can post.

Comment: Just to make sure you are aware, AngularJS is now in End of Life LTS until June 30, 2021. At that time there are no more updates, no security patches. Are you downgrading because of the additional lines of code(boilerplate)? Or is there a technical reason why you can't continue with Angular? https://blog.angular.io/stable-angularjs-and-long-term-support-7e077635ee9c. Additionally, if you really are going to downgrade regardless, are you targeting TS or JS in your downgrade? Which ES version? Are you looking at using modules still?

Comment: I need to downgrade because I a have a lot of code in anguarjs, and no time to re-write it. New code is in angular and I need to use it in my angularjs code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to get rid of boilerplate code, you can get list of components to upgrade, get the selector name for each component and register corresponding directive

1. Get list of your components. This depends on your code structure. The simplest option is to just explicitly return components you need to downgrade. Or you can use `require.context` as you did in your example.

   ```
   function getComponents() {
     // depends on how your components are organized
     // for example, iterate over require.context(".", true, /\.component.ts$/);
     // or return fixed array
     return [ColorPickerComponent, FileSelectComponent];
   }
   ```
2. For each component get the selector name. If you don't use AOT compilation, you can get `selector` value from the `@Component` decorator. But if you do use it, that won't work and you can make a selector from a component name

   ```
   function getComponentSelector(component) {
     // if you don't need AOT
     return toCamelCase(component.__annotations__[0].selector);

     // if you do need it
     let name: string = component.name;
     const suffix = 'Component';
     if (name.endsWith(suffix)) {
       name = name.substr(0, name.length - suffix.length);
     }
     return uncapitalize(name);
   }

   function toCamelCase(selector: string) {
     const splitted = selector.split('-');
     for (let i = 1; i < splitted.length; i++) {
       splitted[i] = capitalize(splitted[i]);
     }
     return splitted.join('');
   }

   function capitalize(name: string) {
     return name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
   }

   function uncapitalize(name: string) {
     return name.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + name.slice(1);
   }
   ```
3. Iterate over your components and register downgraded components

   ```
   downgradeComponents(angular.module('kn-components'));

   function downgradeComponents(module: ng.IModule) {
     const components = getComponents();
     for (const component of components) {
       const selector = getComponentSelector(component);
       module.directive(selector, downgradeComponent({ component }));
     }
   }
   ```